# Vaadin flow 23 losing parent layout on page refresh

Tags: vaadin-flow

We have a Vaadin 23.1.3 application that uses a parent layout for all pages.

The path/urls are dynamically registered and so far this works just fine.

But when a user hits F5, then only the child/main layout is displayed, losing everything from the parent layout.
The same also happens, when a user manually modifies the url to point to another part of the system

When I look at the registered routes, then all routes also have the parentLayout specified

Here the example for the /translations and /translations// routes

[image]

Here is my code for creating the routes

```
protected Button createNavButton(String route, String text, Class<? extends Component> listNavigationTarget, Class<? extends Component> detailNavigationTarget) {
    
    RouteConfiguration configuration = RouteConfiguration.forSessionScope();
    if (configuration.getRoute(route).isEmpty()) {
        try {
            configuration.setRoute(route, listNavigationTarget, getMainLayoutClass());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.error("Error in configuring routes for {} {}", route, text, ex);
        }
        if (detailNavigationTarget != null) {
            try {
                configuration.setRoute(route+"/:primaryKey/:displayTab", detailNavigationTarget, getMainLayoutClass());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                LOG.error("Error in configuring routes for {} {}", route, text, ex);
            }
        }
    }
    Button retVal = new Button(text);
    retVal.setWidthFull();
    retVal.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_TERTIARY);
    retVal.addClickListener((event) -> {
        UI.getCurrent().navigate(route);
    });
    return retVal;
}
```

The `getMainLayoutClass()` method returns the main layout (Based on the AppLayout)

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Losing is spelled l-o-s-i-n-g

Comment: Can you please add some code how you create the routes and use the parent layout

Comment: Source code added where the routes are created dynamically